# XMLRPC java insert issue

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am trying to insert customer details into OpenERP server using XMLPRC and java. I am able to do an authentication. But when i call the execute method to insert the record by passing the parameters, am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException on line res_create = client_1.execute("execute", params_create);

Please find my code below

```
    res = client.execute("login", params);
```

```
        String url_1 = "http://agilewebdevelopment.net:8514/xmlrpc/object";
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config_1 = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        try {
            config_1.setServerURL(new URL(url_1));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("First");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(res);
        HashMap<String, Object> vals = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        vals.put("name", "Mantavya Gajjar");
        vals.put("ref", "MGA");
        XmlRpcClient client_1 = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config_1);
        Object[] params_create = new Object[]{"erp_performance", "1", "admin", "res.partner", "create", vals};

        Object res_create = null;
        try {
             res_create = client_1.execute("execute", params_create);
        } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any helps is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to authentication that means you have working XMLRPC connection, now in case of authentication the OpenERP Services you will be using is common service so you will have client object which will be proxy to `http://host:posrt/xmlrpc/common` that is perfectly right.

But if you want to do any operation on any of the OE Model then for that OE Provides Separate services that is `OBJECT` service so in that case your *client* object must  be proxy to `http://host:port/xmlrpc/object` and then you can call execute method on it, you can see we do not have execute method implemented for the common service on link http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/service/web_services.py#L379

For more you can see [OE and JAVA](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html#id1)

### I have Prepared Some scartch code you try in case

```
package com.xmlrpc.client;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

public class Create {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

Vector params1 = new Vector();
params1.addElement("openerpdb");
params1.addElement("admin");
params1.addElement("admin");

XmlRpcClient xmlrpcLogin = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl xmlrpcConfigLogin = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
xmlrpcConfigLogin.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
xmlrpcConfigLogin.setServerURL(new URL("http", "localhost", 8069, "/xmlrpc/common"));
xmlrpcLogin.setConfig(xmlrpcConfigLogin);

Object id = xmlrpcLogin.execute("login", params1);
System.out.println("Login Id : " + id.toString());

System.out.println("------------------------");

XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl clientConfig = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
clientConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
clientConfig.setServerURL(new URL("http", "localhost", 8069, "/xmlrpc/object"));
client.setConfig(clientConfig);

HashMap<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

params.put("street", "Edamon3");
params.put("partner_id", "24");
params.put("city", "Punalur3");
params.put("name", "ShameerHabeeb3");

Vector<Object> arg = new Vector<Object>();

arg.add("openerpdb");
arg.add(1);
arg.add("admin");
arg.add("res.partner.address");
arg.add("create");
arg.add(params);

Object ret_id = client.execute("execute", arg);
System.out.println("Created new partner address with id :" + ret_id.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback jam.... i have edited my code to call the object...edited code is updated in the thread...Now am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" on line  res_create = client_1.execute("execute", params_create);

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 1.4 then it is not able to to auto-boxing . 
so may be try this

Object[] params_create = new Object[]{"erp_performance", "1", "admin", "res.partner", "create", vals};

just pass uid in string

or

also possibility is that for log in you have to use "http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common"
and for object methods you have to use "http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object"

check for the both and you will have you solution .

Answer (score 0):

Try to know the parameters which you need to send in order to that execution. You are facing this error because of the parameter mismatch.

Are you sure that `1` which is being sent is in fact expecting an integer or string ? Once you are sure on the types of the parameters expected, you can get rid of this exception.

Comment: 1 is actually the userid of the loggged in user. I tried by providing the following code but got same error
Object[] params_create = new Object[]{"erp_performance", res, "admin", "res.partner", "create", vals};

Comment: When I started working on xmlrpc, I had faced similar issue for days. Then on sending the expected param types, problem was solved. Know the types they are expecting. If the method is expecting String and we are passing an int, it will throw an error.